Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
On my local machine it runs well. on CircleCi it fails with this error.
I'm using java 17.
gradle 8.5
and the following -

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4G -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options=-Xmx2G
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseParallelGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

any ideas?

The fix for me was in my yml file.
I had -
executor: android-builder
resource_class: small

and needed to fix it to -
executor: android-builder
resource_class: large

